# Google Maps direction API returns zero result for transit when using departure date

Tags: java, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the Google direction and Google distance API for getting information about travel time and costs between two points at a specified time.

That works pretty well for the travel modes walking, bicycling and driving. But when I use the travel mode transit it only works if I pass no departure or arrival date and time. If I pass a specific date or time, I get a Zero result in the distance API and I get the following output in the direction API:

```
 <DirectionsResponse>
   <status>ZERO_RESULTS</status>
   <available_travel_mode>DRIVING</available_travel_mode>
   <available_travel_mode>BICYCLING</available_travel_mode>
   <available_travel_mode>WALKING</available_travel_mode>
   <geocoded_waypoint>
     <geocoder_status>OK</geocoder_status>
     <type>locality</type>
     <type>political</type>
     <place_id>ChIJx8qYb7jUpEcRMD6slG2sJQQ</place_id>
   </geocoded_waypoint>
   <geocoded_waypoint>
     <geocoder_status>OK</geocoder_status>
     <type>locality</type>
     <type>political</type>
     <place_id>ChIJEXrwv2AXuUcRUIdUMYHyJwQ</place_id>
   </geocoded_waypoint>
 </DirectionsResponse>
```

Used URL: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Göttingen&destination=Dortmund&mode=transit&departure_time=1502538805000&key=APIKEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=G%C3%B6ttingen&destination=Dortmund&mode=transit&departure_time=1502538805000&key=APIKEY)

Has anyone an idea why that returns a zero result always?

Comment: Perhaps because as the response indicates TRANSIT isn't one of the "available" modes

Comment: If I don't pass a departure or arrival date it works fine. If I use the same query for the distance API it only returns zero result without the other stuff. The documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) tells that it should work.

Comment: Is the departure time valid?

Comment: Your right, I was using milliseconds instead of seconds for the departure time. When using seconds it works fine. Thanks for the hint, don't know why I overlooked that all the time. Thanks a lot @geocodezip

Answer (score 1):

like geocodezip wrote in the comments above,

the problem was that I used milliseconds instead of seconds for the departure_time.